# Vertx WebClient Using Too Many File Descriptors

Tags: java, netty, vert.x, file-descriptor

I am trying to run a vertx WebClient within AWS Lambda. AWS Lambdas have a max of 1024 file descriptors and are non-adjustable. I am having trouble finding what exactly is using up all of my file descriptors. I am only using the WebClient from vertx and not running any verticles. Here is my shared WebClient:

```
var webClientOptions = new WebClientOptions()
                .setSsl(true)
                .setUseAlpn(true)
                .setReusePort(true)
                .setDefaultPort(443)
                .setHttp2MaxPoolSize(30)
                .setProtocolVersion(HttpVersion.HTTP_2)
                .setSslHandshakeTimeout(30)
                .setIdleTimeout(5)
                .setIdleTimeoutUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return WebClient.create(vertx, webClientOptions);
```

This client is reused between lambda invocations, and never closed.

How I am using it:

```
var requestFutures = new ArrayList<CompletableFuture<Foo>>();
for (var request : requests) {
  CompletableFuture<Foo> future = new CompletableFuture();
  requestFutures.add(future);

  Buffer buffer = Buffer.buffer(request.getPayload());
  httpRequest.sendBuffer(buffer, (res) -> {
    future.complete(res);
  });
}

for (var requestFuture : requestFutures) {
  requestFuture.get();
}
```

Where I have 45k-65k requests to send. What I get is:

```
io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to open a socket.
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.newSocket(NioSocketChannel.java:70)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.<init>(NioSocketChannel.java:87)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.<init>(NioSocketChannel.java:80)
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:320)
at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:163)
at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:145)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ChannelProvider.handleConnect(ChannelProvider.java:140)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ChannelProvider.connect(ChannelProvider.java:93)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpChannelConnector.doConnect(HttpChannelConnector.java:171)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpChannelConnector.connect(HttpChannelConnector.java:105)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.pool.Pool$Holder.connect(Pool.java:125)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.pool.Pool.checkPendingTasks(Pool.java:250)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:474)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(Unknown Source)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.newSocket(NioSocketChannel.java:68)
... 17 more
```

When I run this locally and watch the open files/sockets in the OSX Activity Monitor it shoots up to thousands. I don't understand why it's doing this based on how i've configured the `WebClientOptions`.

Can someone tell from this information why I would be using so many file descriptors?

Answer (score 0):

setHttp2MaxPoolSize(30) is a lot, in theory you only need 1 because it is HTTP/2